# Jogo da Cobrinha no javascript

Tags: javascript

Ola,

Estou fazendo o jogo da cobrinha e estou com um problema onde, eu aperto para a esquerda e cobra vai para a esquerda, porem quando eu aberto em seguida para a direita, ela também vai como se ela "se atravessasse" e dai queria saber como é possível que eu pare esse comportamento dela ir para as direções contraias:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var stage = document.getElementById("stage") ;
    var ctx = stage.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown" , keyPush)
    

    setInterval(game, 1000/15);

    const vel = 1;

    var vx = vy = 0;

    var px = py = 10

    var tp = 20;
    
    var qp = 20;

    var ax = ay = 15

    var trail = []
    tail = 10;


    function game(){
    px += vx;
    py += vy;

    if (px < 0){
        px = qp-1;
    }

    if (px > qp - 1){
        px = 0;
    }

    if (py < 0 ){
        py = qp-1;
    }

    if (py > qp - 1){
        py = 0
    }


    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, stage.width , stage.height)

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*tp, ay*tp , tp,tp)

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    for(var i = 0; i < trail.length; i++){
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*tp , trail[i].y*tp , tp,tp)

        if(trail[i].x == px && trail[i].y == py){
            
            tail = 5
        }
    }
        trail.push({x:px , y:py})
        while(trail.length > tail){
            trail.shift();
        }

        if (ax == px && ay==py){
            tail++;
            ax = Math.floor(Math.random()*qp);
            ay = Math.floor(Math.random()*qp);
        }

    }

    function keyPush(event){
        switch(event.keyCode){
            case 37 : //LEFT
                vx = -vel;
                vy = 0;
            break;

            case 38://UP
                vx = 0;
                vy = -vel;
            break;

            case 39://RIGHT
                vx = vel;
                vy = 0;
            break;

            case 40://DOWN
                vx = 0;
                vy = vel;
            break;

            default:

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: crie uma variavel e salve a última direção que a cobra tomou, ai compare para ver se a nova direção é válida

Comment: esquerda direita podem ser representadas pelos pixels na direção desejada.. na posição x  cada vez que é direcionado a direita pode ser atribuido +=1.. para esquerda ira remover uma posição -= 1...

Answer (score -2):

Acho que um jeito tranquilo seria uma function() para traduzir o movimento.
Algo para se basear

```
// Virtualiza utimo angulo
let flagXY;
// Função de conversão de direçao em movimento
function moveSnake(direction){
    // Verifica o angulo de movimento
    if(direction == 'L'  || direction == 'R'){
        switch(direction){
            // Caso a direção seja left
            case 'L' : 
                if(y){
                    // Atribui a direção
                    vx = -vel;
                    vy = 0;
                }
            break;
            // Caso a direção seja right
            case 'R':
            {
                vx = vel;
                vy = 0;
                break;
            }
            default:
            break;
        }
        // Atribui a flag de movimento
        flagXY = x
    }
    // Verifica o angulo de movimento
    if(direction == 'U'  || direction == 'D'){
        switch(direction){
            // Caso a direção seja UP
            case 'U':
                vx = 0;
                vy = -vel;
            break;
            // Caso a direção seja DOWN
            case 'D':
                vx = 0;
                vy = vel;
            break;
            
        }
          // Atribui o angulo de movimento
          flagXY = x
    }
}
```

Obs: não compilei só escrevi no notes, então da uma concertada se houver erro de digit

Answer (score -2):

Basta verificar antes se a velocidade não está no seu oposto, por exemplo, no `case 37`, verifique antes de alterar a `vx` se a cobra não está se movendo na direção oposta, isto é `vx == +vel`. Ficaria algo como:

```
case 37 : //LEFT
    if (vx == vel) return; // Cancela a alteração de movimento
    vx = -vel;
    vy = 0;
    break;
```

No caso o `return` depois da verificação vai fazer com que o código saia da função `keyPush`, cancelando as mudanças de velocidade. Faça o mesmo para as demais movimentações, verificando se a velocidade não é a oposta.

Sugiro fortemente que você altere os nomes das variáveis para algo mais legível como `velocidadeX`, `velocidadeY`, `velocidade`. Acostume-se a usar variáveis com nome significativo, pois vai facilitar muito a leitura do seu código, mesmo que retorne para ele depois de muito tempo.

Eu mesmo nem investiguei para saber o que `qp` e `tp` no seu código, pois são nomes muito crípticos, difíceis de saber o que são. Essa prática era comum em programadores lá da antiga em linguagens como Fortran ou Assembly que limitavam  o tamanho dos nomes das variáveis, e no fim tinha que perfurar os cartões para representar cada caractere, então quanto maior o programa e nomes de variáveis, mais cartões você precisaria. Hoje isso não faz sentido algum.

Hoje, o maior lema do programador deve ser: "quanto mais legível o seu código (sem precisar de comentários) melhor ele é"!